# Chain ID set to 1(provided 15) while creating private net using Geth

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, mist

[{
  "difficulty" : "0x20000",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "0x8000000",
  "alloc": {},
  "config": {
        "chainId": 15,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    }
}]

this is my genesis.json file & as mention chainid is 15.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing double dash in front of the datadir parameter. It should be `geth --datadir=<YOUR_DATA_DIR> console`. So you are reading from other directory.

You have to use the same `--datadir` when creating your private blockchain with `geth --datadir=<YOUR_DATA_DIR> init <YOUR_GENESIS_FILE>`.